# finding real roots for $f'(x)$ under given conditions

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

> Let $f(x) = (x − a)(x − b)^
> 3
> (x − c)^
> 5
> (x − d)^
> 7$
> , where $a, b, c, d$ are real numbers with
> $a < b < c < d$. Thus $f(x)$ has $16$ real roots counting multiplicities and among them $4$ are
> distinct from each other. Consider $f
> '
> (x)$, i.e. the derivative of $f(x)$. Find the following, if
> you can: $(i)$ the number of real roots of $f
> '
> (x)$, counting multiplicities, $(ii)$ the number of
> distinct real roots of $f
> '
> (x)$.

Here, I tried differentiating the function to get $f'(x)=(x-b)^3(x-c)^5(x-d)^7+3(x-a)(x-b)^2(x-c)^5(x-d)^7+5(x-a)(x-b)^3(x-c)^4(x-d)^7+7(x-a)(x-b)^3(x-c)^5(x-d)^6$

$f'(x)=-(x - b)^2 (x - c)^4 (x - d)^6 (7 a b c + 5 a b d - 12 a b x + 3 a c d - 10 a c x - 8 a d x + 15 a x^2 + b c d - 8 b c x - 6 b d x + 13 b x^2 - 4 c d x + 11 c x^2 + 9 d x^2 - 16 x^3) = 0$

We clearly have $12$ roots (including multipicity) from the first three terms of $f'(x)$, but checking the cubic equation for real roots seems way too much lengthy and complex for such a question. Thus I believe that my approach might not be correct.

Please provide a hint as how to approach this question. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

***THANKS***

Comment: If I draw a picture (or use Rolle!) I see at least one root of $f'$ in $(a,b)$, $(b,c)$ and $(c,d)$.  So with the $12$ you've got we've accounted for $15 $ roots of $f'$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician That was good. I didn't actually think of that. Thanks for help and also consider posting your comment as an answer.

Comment: for what its worth - Not only is your approach **correct**, your approach is **required**.  That is, your evaluation of $f'(x)$ is **accurate**.  Therefore, regardless of whether the problem succumbs to *elegant insight*, **any** solution must accommodate your *accurate* computation of $f'(x)$.

Comment: @user2661923: I beg to differ; the effort in calculating the cubic factor explicitly is "wasted".

Comment: @user2661923, that is correct, but I don't see why I needed to calculate the cubic part when a maximum of $15$ roots are obtained after analysing the first three terms and rolle's theorem. I couldn't have got more than $15$ roots, thus solving the cubic won't have served any purpose, especially for a contest problem.

Comment: I agree that you don't have to *necessarily* explicitly calculate the cubic factor, but you do have to understand the nature of the function $f'(x)$.  Personally, my intuition on a problem like this is *so* unsophisticated, that I would force myself to explicitly write down $f'(x)$.  It seems to me that taking shortcuts here is only appropriate if you are very confident in the sophistication of your intuition.  That doesn't mean that I would necessarily attempt to *solve* $f'(x) = 0.$

Comment: @user2661923 The proper method here would be to explicitly calculate $f'(x)$ to check its nature. You are absolutely right, but in a contest where you have to answer the question within $2-3$ minutes, solving such a cubic equation is generally not the better approach despite being the general approach.

Comment: I still think that drawing a picture is the way to go before one does any calculations. It takes a moment to sketch $f$ and then another to roughly sketch $f'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the 12 roots at $b,c,d$ (counting multiplicities) we see that $f'$ has at least one root in each of the intervals $(a,b), (b,c),(c,d)$. As the degree of $f'$ is fifteen, these three roots are simple.